# Just how much self-promotion is allowed?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, moderation

We have a user who apparently logged in to answer [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/how-do-i-go-about-finding-a-graphic-designer-for-a-personal-job) as though it were a Craigslist ad. I'm thinking this is a no-no. Am I correct? Can we just delete the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not. The answer has been deleted.