# I think its time to consolidate and lock the stock questions

Tags: discussion

Given this discussion: [How to curb self-promotion without scaring new users away?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/how-to-curb-self-promotion-without-scaring-new-users-away)

And now we've got [Simon Steinberger](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/23120/simon-steinberger), the head developer of Pixabay, adding his site to as many of them as possible. Since we're out of Beta I think its an excellent time for us to consolidate and then either lock or delete some of these:

- [Where are some good places to find royalty free stock images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-royalty-free-stock-images) (4k views)
- [Where can I get images for commercial use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6799/where-can-i-get-images-for-commercial-use) (10k views)
- [Free vector graphic images, for commercial use](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12920/free-vector-graphic-images-for-commercial-use) (13k views)
- [Which is the Best and more reliable Free Vector Graphics Site?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30644/which-is-the-best-and-more-reliable-free-vector-graphics-site) (new today)
- [Free vector graphic images, for commercial use](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12920/free-vector-graphic-images-for-commercial-use)

There's probably more too. What do you all think? And is it worth having one question Vector and one question Photo despite most of these sites supplying both or should we consolidate entirely into one question -- Where to find royalty-free images, photos, vectors and illustrations?

Answer (score 3):

I agree it is a little messy. I'm not really sure if one or two questions is correct, it depends on the number of answers all of the almost-duplicates have, and how much it can be organised.

I'm just answering to say the title you've come up with is ok but it seems like it covers too much. Photos and illustrations *are* images I think - making it odd.

Here are some options I've thought of:

- Where can I find royalty-free pixel and vector images?

Short and sweet.

- What websites provide royalty-free pixel- and vector-based images for commercial use?

More descriptive and likely to be better for SEO.

Comment: I like these! Even a mix of the two: "Where can I find royalty-free pixel and vector images for commercial use?". We can actually merge questions/answers, I agree it would be great to have one main question and redirect others to it.

Comment: Do you all really think people search by "royalty free pixel" anything? I know I've never used pixel in a search query. I say "royalty free photos." Do Mods have any access to site analytics or can we find out from a staff member to see what terms people are using?

Comment: @Ryan I make a pretty unfounded assumption that when coupled with  'vector' and placed before 'images', Google will understand it's meaning better. I could so easily be wrong.